# A and complement A

Tags: probability, probability-theory

So if A is independent, what can we say about A and complement A, are they independent or not, or undetermined?

I think that when both happen then A and complement A intersect would be zero, then they are not independent. Unless A is empty then they are undetermined. Am I correct?

Comment: Have you asked yourself: What is the probability of both happening?

Comment: "if $A$ is independent"...from what?

Comment: "they are undetermined" What does this mean?

Answer (score 2):

If they're independent, then $P(A \cap A') = P(A)P(A')$. It's obvious that $P(A \cap A') = 0$, so you can figure out what $P(A)P(A')$ is to get your answer.

Comment: So there are exactly two special cases under which $A$ and $A'$ are independant